# Return value upto 5 decimals

Tags: python, decimal

I have defined a function population density and returns the value. How do I define the function and limit the value until 5 decimals?

```
#write your function here:
def population_density(population, area):
    calc = (population/area)
    return(calc)


# test cases for your function
test2 = population_density(864816, 121.4)
expected_result2 = 7123.6902801
print("expected re`strong text`sult: {}, actual result: {}".format(expected_result2, 
test2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function to do this!

```
def population_density(population, area):
   calc = population/area
   return round(calc, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

**A quick note: Rounding in Python may not always work as expected. Proceed with caution.**

I think the `round(number[, ndigits])` function is the easiest here. For your case, it seems you're looking to always round to 5 decimals. We can force this in the return value:

```
def population_density(population, area):
                calc = (population/area)
                return(round(calc, 5))
```

Alternatively, you may want to specify the number of digits to round to for various reasons. We can do this with a new parameter, `round_`:

```
def population_density(population, area, round_):
                calc = (population/area)
                return(round(calc, round_))
```

You can read more about `round()` here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

As you'll see in the documentation, when a value rounds in a way you do not expect,

> This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float.

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you operate [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) so you won't loose the precision.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal('7123.6902801')
>>> round(a, 5)
Decimal('7123.69028')
```

Also if you want to just print if, you can format it to certain decimal places without changing/creating value:

```
>>> "{0:.5f}".format(Decimal('7123.6902801'))
```